# Release Resources from Waiting Thread Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I don't know which type, this question could be and I just feeling risky to ask it.

I was reading [wait notify and notifyall](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-use-wait-notify-and-notifyall-in.html) and there I got a good example about Producer and Consumer. Both thread inter-communicating using wait and notifyall(); Ok Understood why. But I just thinking that if Producer is working then Consumer is waiting even using resources. Suppose producer need to work for a long time then Consumer still waiting and using resources.

Now I want to ask is there a way to release resources(CPU/RAM: any resources that used by waiting) from threads those are on waiting? or waiting never consume resources(CPU/RAM)?

Comment: depends on what releasing resources means

Comment: A thread that `wait()`s does not hold the lock / blocks the resource so there is nothing to release.

Comment: @zapl but also in waiting condition... and waiting mean alive(using CPU resources)

Comment: `lock.wait()` will 1) release the lock and 2) send the thread to sleep. No longer "alive" and about 0 CPU (there is no effect on RAM, your objects are all still there). Then when someone calls `lock.notify()` the waiting thread wakes up and tries to re-acquire the lock. If it can't it's going to sleep again. If it succeeds it will consume CPU.

Comment: @zapl i think you updated comment before my next question. Thanks :) exactly what i was looking for..!!

Comment: @UnKnown A thread that is blocked in `o.wait()` does _not_ use any CPU cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have some very unusual situation where you have a demonstrated problem, you should just do things the regular way. Nothing in your question suggests anything unusual about your use case, so there's no reason to try to find some kind of unusual solution.

Don't make things complicated just for the sake of fixing some imaginary problem you have no evidence of.

Comment: I didn't just asked the solution, I also asked the reason if any then what should be the solution. Any How thanks I got the point by zapl's comment.